# React listening mouseEnter event only after mouseDown event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mouseevent

How can I listen to mouseEnter event only after mouseDown event fired?

In the following example I'm trying to select multiple cells on mouseEnter, and leave blank on mouseLeave event. But, I don't have any idea where to put mouseDown event and listen to other events.

```js
class GameSearchWord extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleMouseEnter = this.handleMouseEnter.bind(this)
    this.handleMouseLeave = this.handleMouseLeave.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      cells: [
        { id: 1, selected: false },
        { id: 2, selected: false },
        { id: 3, selected: false },
        { id: 4, selected: false },
        { id: 5, selected: false },
        { id: 6, selected: false },
        { id: 7, selected: false },
        { id: 8, selected: false },
        { id: 9, selected: false },
        { id: 10, selected: false },
      ]
    }
  }

  handleMouseEnter(id) {
    this.setState({
      cells: this.state.cells.map(cell => {
        if (cell.id === id) {
          return {
            id,
            selected: true
          }
        }
        return cell
      })
    })
  }

  handleMouseLeave() {
    this.setState({
      cells: this.state.cells.map(cell => ({
        id: cell.id,
        selected: false
      }))
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.cells.map(cell => (
          <li
            key={cell.id}
            className={cell.selected ? 'active' : ''}
            onMouseEnter={() => this.handleMouseEnter(cell.id)}
            onMouseLeave={() => this.handleMouseLeave()}>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<GameSearchWord />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.active {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: i believe you will want to save a key on state that would tell if mousedown is used. and if followed by mouseenter run the handler. else set to false

Comment: @ReiDien i got the trick, thanks. How can I listen for mouseUp event outside my component?

Comment: in your didMount function `element.addEventListener('mousedown', handler)` in your handler you then attach your listeners for mouseenter and mouseleave. use `addEventListener` for the listeners.

Comment: @JohnRuddell How can I select my li element? Using ref?

Comment: Now you're selecting based on mousenter, correct? But is its so you want to select based on mouse click?